# How to validate secrets in flask config

Tags: python, flask

[Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/config/#development-production) suggests splitting development and production configuration using classes. I have such classes defined in my `config.py`:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(24)
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = None
    MY_API_KEY = None

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://{username}:{password}@{server}/{db}'.format(
        username=os.getenv('MYSQL_USERNAME'),
        password=os.getenv('MYSQL_PASSWORD'),
        server=os.getenv('MYSQL_SERVER'),
        db=os.getenv('MYSQL_DATABASE')
        )
    MY_API_KEY = os.getenv('MY_API_KEY')

class DevelopmentConfig(Config):
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite://database.db'
    MY_API_KEY = os.getenv('MY_API_KEY', 'fake_api_key')
```

`Config` is a base class with common settings.
`ProductionConfig` is using real database and real api keys.
`DevelopmentConfig` is using local sqlite database and either real api keys or dummy keys.

This works great for local development. I can use DevelopmentConfig with default settings to quickly launch and test my application. I can also provide API key when I need to test parts using API.

However, in production I would like to be sure `MY_API_KEY` and mysql credentials are always provided. Application should refuse to launch (with clear error message), if any of those environment variables are not defined. I can do:

```
    MY_API_KEY = os.environ['MY_API_KEY']
```

but this will crash during module load (and will make DevelopmentConfig unusable).

Is there a standard way to validate configuration? Do I need to redesign the way I load my configs?

Comment: How are you loading the config into the app object in each environment?

Comment: After loading the config you can loop over the app.config keys using a separate 'config_constants' file?

Comment: @LuisOrduz I'm loading it via: `app.config.from_object("config." + selected_config)`

Comment: @Erik that will work for `MY_API_KEY` but not for `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI `.

Comment: and how are you setting the `selected_config` variable?

Comment: @LuisOrduz passed via command line arguments.

Comment: You could write the classes in different files then, and just pass `config.prod.ProductionConfig` or similar depending on the environment.